# Does facebook graph api needs image url for displaying image?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have a webpage and a F-Share button. On clicking this button, an image uploaded by the user is posted on facebook. I tried to initially use javascript to set the 'picture' property with image data from fileupload and it didn't work. So, my guess is that, Facebook does'nt save the images to its server but instead fetches them and displays them from the url we provide. Is that the case? If not, please guide me how can I use the image from fileupload in the 'picture' property?

Comment: Please explain "image from fileupload in the 'picture' property".

Comment: There is a "FileUpload" (ASP.NET) control on the page. When the user chooses an image in the control. Then, I want to set this image in the 'picture' property of the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the thumbnail that is posted on the FB wall when sharing a page, you can control what image is used by defining some `META` tags. Here are some examples from the docs:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Look under "Sharing Rich Media"